# Can anyone tell me how to create the outline on this text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

Anyone have any idea how to create the outline on the letters in 'Beautiful'?

I've tried adding a drop shadow and stroke, I'm hoping to have the white space between the letter and the outline though.

[image: Beautiful]

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I've tried adding a drop-shadow to it and played around with stroke a little bit. The shadow would be sufficient, but I'm trying to create a space between the letter and the outline. I actually have a higher reputation but I didn't sign in, stupidly. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that info. Short 'how do I do this' questions without any sign of previous effort are strongly disliked here and will quickly attract both close votes and downvotes.

Comment: Moreover, please do not use two different accounts to post here. Please follow [these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your two accounts. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean to, I've never seen a post as guest box before and this is also my first time in the graphic design section, sorry!

Comment: @Rob: in that case you may want to read the introductory [tour], and possibly browse the [help] as well.

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this is to do the following.

1. Create your text in Photoshop.

[image: Create your text]

2. Hide the background layer so you can see what you are doing for this step. Add a stroke layer style and change the color to the color of your background and the size slider is to change the size of the boarder between the text and the fancy outline you're creating.

[image: Layer style]
[image: Stroke]

3. Click OK and then in the layers panel, right click on stroke and choose Create layer. This will convert the style into a layer so you can add a style to that and since it's separate from the text layer, it can always be made to match you background.

[image: Create layer from stroke]

4. Select the new layer that was created and add a Drop shadow layer style and set the blend mode to normal with the opacity at 100%. Change the size slider to 0 to get a solid shadow and not blurry and adjust the angle to look good on your text. The last thing to do is to change the color of your fancy outline to whatever you want then click OK.

[image: Drop shadow]

5. Final result.

[image: Result]

As always. this can probably be achieved using many other methods.